# In MySQL, when should we use IF() over CASE...WHEN and vice versa?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, when are the specific cases when to use the IF() statement over the CASE...WHEN statement, and vice versa?

Please include specific scenarios/queries.

Comment: The same when you are using `if ()` or `switch case` in a programming language

Comment: *"Please include specific scenarios/queries."* We are not here to do the thinking for you.. Also @isaace has given a valid user case already, when to use which flow control option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`If` is only for 2 options, `CASE WHEN` can have multiple options.

Comment: But you can just do something like an elseif, right? For example: SELECT if(occupation = 'Doctor', name, if(occupation = 'Professor', name, null)) FROM occupations;

Comment: IF() looks more concise for shorter statements, but CASE is better for more complex ones. Accepting you answer :)